# What portion of Hindus believe that deities are mere fiction?

Tags: belief

I see varying degrees of deity "devotion" in Hinduism within the structure of the Vedas. The samhitas and brahmanas provide rituals and a mythos to illustrate use of the principles behind them. The aranyakas provide some specific concerns for later in life and the upanishads allow for ishta devata or even advaita where we and god are one as brahmin.

- What percentage of all Hindus believe that the gods are merely mythical in nature?

Comment: Why the 2nd question on Secular aspect.  It has no relevance to the core question content

Comment: because I wish to know? is that not enough? why do I have to say why I wish to know?

Comment: Both are different questions.  In my view, it is better to ask a separate question on that topic

Comment: sorry SK but that does not tell me anything about the numbers who AREN'T at those temples or in those lines.

Comment: well, that combined with the fact that you have many unable to get to temple or pursue a tirtha. There are many who practice only in their homes and follow a manas tirtha.

Comment: No offense intended SK but your stats do not say that no one is unable to go to temple.

Comment: @KauvaAatma: It is very difficult to answer this particular question - **What percentage of all Hindus believe that the gods are merely mythical in nature?** in my view.  In general Hindus will not come out openly and say "Yes!  I do believe that the gods are merely mythical in nature".  It is not because of the fact that the Hindus don't understand the issue, but due to the fact that there are multiple ways looking at the issue.

Comment: @KauvaAatma:  A kid will be given one alphabet or one number at a time, keeping in view of its age, to keep on writing over the same for number of days together.  A scholar will read voluminous books containing many such alphabets or numbers at a go.  In between there will be so many levels of understanding depending upon understanding levels of individuals.

Comment: @KauvaAatma: A spiritual aspirant , who is at the beginning stage, may not understand the higher concepts of Rig Veda or the words of Sri Ramana Maharshi.  However, the same person may understand a little, if one is given one name to repeat, like rAma, or to do puja of a particular deity daily at a prescribed time say early in the morning, and one may practice that also.  It is sufficient for one to keep oneself attached to SPIRITUAL realm, according to one's understanding.  Later one can move one, understanding higher concepts of SPIRITUALITY. So idol worship has its own advantages.

Comment: @SK just because I dont agree with your choice of reference material doesn't mean I am "here to argue". I wish to know relative percentages of Hindu religious affiliations including the Vedantic.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreligion_in_India

> The religion data from 2011 Census of India was released in August 2015. **It revealed that about 2,870,000 people had stated no religion in their response, about 0.27% of the nation's population.[85] However, the number included atheists, rationalists and also those who believed in a higher power.** K. Veeramani, a Dravidar Kazhagam leader, said that it was the first time the number of non-religious people was recorded in the census. However, he added that he believed that the number of atheists in India was actually higher as many people don't reveal their atheism out of fear.[86]

I assume you are asking for people who consider themselves Hindus but are atheists - that answer would be hard to get.

Comment: wow, less than 1%! That's incredible.

Comment: See the predictions of the Kali yuga are wrong!

Comment: @Ikshvaku Really, are the Abrahamic faiths any better? At least Atheists will likely give up their beliefs on getting evidence. The others will claim demons/djinn who always seem to be more powerful than their gods are.

Comment: @Wikash_ I don't think there actually is a prophecy of more atheists. Atheistic philosophies yes, but I think that's just because the authors are tired of humans having stupid beliefs about the supreme God.

Comment: Authors of what?